# How to set a child's height to 100% of a parent element using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently having an issue where whenever I attempt to have a child take up 100% of the remaining height of a container, the child's height expands way past the border of the parent.

**HTML**

```css
.container {
  height: 340px;
  /* background-image: url(../images/topo-bg-3-black.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  background-color: #DDDEDA;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-wrap {
height: 200px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.content {
height: 100%;
width: 171px;
background-color: aqua;
}

.content-pic {
 width: 100%;
height: 115px;
background-color: green;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.content-text {
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="content">
    5 HOURS AGO
        <div class="content-pic"></div>
        <div class="content-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JSFiddle containing my code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bqswtuLa/1/).

I've attempted using **align-items: stretch;** as well as the **position** property as other threads have suggested to no avail. The width takes up 100% of the container just fine, but the height doesn't, and I'm a bit stuck on what to do.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the height of the red element based on a hard coded height of the green element? If so, you could use this: 

  .content-text { height: calc(100% - 115px); }

Comment: I do not know if this is okay:    <div class="content" style="overflow:hidden;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collected two solutions for you.

The first one(As I said in the comment area) is to using *overflow: hidden* to hide the overflow part of the element:

```
.content {
height: 100%;
width: 171px;
background-color: aqua;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The second one is **solve this problem completely**, I determined that the *content-pic* of its *height* you are using is *115px* but not percent, so the thing will overflow, so here is the solution:

```
  .content-pic {
   width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .content-text {
  background-color: red;
  height: calc(100ph - 115px);
  width: 100%;

  }
```

The reason why it will overflow at the beginning is that you put two elements, one has 115px size, and another has 100% size, so the second one's top position is 115px while the width is still 100%.

In that case, I change *width:100%* into *calc(100ph - 115px)*. *100ph* is similar to *100%*, and *115px* is the height of *content-pic*.

Furthermore, please using *span* instead of using nothing because if you do not do that, it will not work in some case.

This is the whole code(For the second solution):

```css
.container {
    height: 340px;
    background-color: #DDDEDA;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .container-wrap {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
  .content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 171px;
  background-color: aqua;

  }
  
  .content-pic {
   width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .content-text {
  background-color: red;
  height: calc(100% - 115px);
  width: 100%;

  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="content">
    <span>
      5 HOURS AGO
      </span>
        <div class="content-pic"></div>
        <div class="content-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```